# Dois-je conjuger à l'impératif ce verbe dans cette phrase, quand je donne un ordre au public: "quelqu'un vient/s m'aider"?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, syntaxe, mode-grammatical, impératif

Je commence à mélanger le Français avec l'Anglais car en Anglais si je veux demander l'assistance de quelqu'un, il faut que je dise "someone come with me please", et non pas "someone comes..." car on utilise le mode impératif même avec les pronoms 3e pers singulier.

Je me demande alors, si je veux écrire cette sorte de phrase en Français, dois-je mettre le verbe en mode impératif?

Par exemple quand je parle à plusieurs personnes, dois-je mettre les verbes à l'impératif ou dois-je les conjuguer normalement (au présent de l'indicatif)? Ex: *"quelqu'un [viens/vient] ici"* ou *"quelqu'un [prends/prend] ce sac rapidement"* ?

J'hésite entre le mode impératif et indicatif, car à la fois je donne un ordre, mais il y a aussi le mot "quelqu'un" qui me dit de conjuguer à la 3e pers singulier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonjour,

Il n'y a pas d'impératif pour la troisième personne en français, et par ailleurs on ne mentionne pas le sujet avec l'impératif. On peut exprimer l'ordre en utilisant des formulations légèrement différentes, mais il n'y a pas de traduction littérale de la forme anglaise:

1. Le plus souvent, on s'adresse à un public avec une phrase interrogative (et donc l'indicatif):

Est-ce que quelqu'un viendrait m'aider ?
Qui veut bien m'aider ? Qui vient m'aider ?

2. Pour se rapprocher de l'ordre, on peut également utiliser le subjonctif

Il faut que quelqu'un vienne m'aider !
(rem : on peut aussi utiliser "Que quelqu'un vienne m'aider", mais c'est une formulation qui a tendance à disparaître).

3. L'impératif reste possible, mais alors obligatoirement à la 2ème personne. C'est plutôt le cas pour les actions précises une fois que la personne est plus ou moins identifiée, mais en général on donne un ordre à une personne ou un groupe précis. Dans votre cas, l'emploi de l'impératif à la 2ème personne est tout à fait adéquat pour donner un ordre à quelqu'un dans le public. Je ne chercherais pas une traduction littérale.

Venez ici! Prenez ce sac rapidement!

rem: l'utilisation du "vous" en français s'applique aussi bien à une (vouvoiment poli) qu'à plusieurs personnes (pluriel). Dans certains spectacle, l'artiste tutoie le public mais cela dépend du personnage (le tutoiement d'inconnus peut être perçu comme un style "agressif", à manier avec un humour plutôt sarcastique)

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Mais alors si je veux écrire des phrases comme l'exemple dans la question, dois-je conjuger à l'indicatif, même si je donne un ordre? Est-il possible par exemple d'écrire "quelqu'un vient ici"? Bonne journée.

Comment: @Eren8hisfather l'indicatif n'est en général pas le bon mode pour marquer un souhait, une injonction. A la rigueur un indicatif futur : "quelqu'un viendra ici, s'il vous plait ?" mais la possibilité d'un délai que cela introduit est contradictoire avec le caractère immédiat de la demande de l'exemple d'origine.

Comment: @Eren8hisfather mon conseil est de ne pas essayer de reproduire littéralement le "someone help me please" parce qu'il est plus naturel de dire "aidez-moi, SVP!" en français.

Answer (score 2):

Lorsqu'on veut formuler une phrase injonctive et que l'impératif ne possède pas la personne voulue, on peut utiliser la conjonction exclamative *que* + subjonctif :

> Que quelqu'un vienne prendre ce sac rapidement !

Mais le plus souvent, l'impératif pluriel fait l'affaire :

> Venez prendre ce sac rapidement !

Et si on veut absolument utiliser *quelqu'un* :

> Quelqu'un! Venez prendre ce sac rapidement !

https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/phrase-imperative

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que I.C.1.

[https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quelqu'un](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quelqu%27un) II.A.2.c)